# Rails check_box_tag is not uncheck the value when update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have one check box in the html form,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[product_groups_attributes][2][product_group_items_attributes][2][pre_select]">
```

and if I checked the checkbox it will update the value as true, then in the edit form I am having this

```
<%= check_box_tag "product[product_groups_attributes][#{v1}][product_group_items_attributes][#{t1}][pre_select]", 1, product_group_item.pre_select %>
```

But here when I uncheck the checkbox and submit the form, the value is not updating to false.

Comment: Can you please show the server logs when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes @gwalshington that shows still "0"=>{"pre_select"=>"1"}

Comment: Please post the full server logs, and all relevant code if you'd like help debugging :)

Comment: @gwalshington All other values are updating perfectly, other than this checkbox value, i am suspecting something is happening with the checkbox

Comment: its good if you provide controller code and developer logs

Answer (score 2):

This is default behaviour of a checkbox, form only sends data when the checkbox is checked

Your Rails backend need to check if the checkbox is present in the params and if not that means its false.

Comment: oh, is there any way we can achieve with attributes? without js

Comment: That is not true at all. The form sends all the data - 'false' is data just like 'true' is data.

Comment: I did not say form doesn't send all data, what I said is that a unchecked checkbox value does not get sent in a post.

You can implement this with having two radio buttons with same name and values are true and false.

Comment: Here is a couple of references to this http://dustinbolton.com/submit-unchecked-checkbox-value/ https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?113263-how-to-send-a-value-for-a-checkbox-when-it-is-unchecked

Comment: @rajbir interesting... I think the statement only holds true for certain form structures. I do not encounter this issue with a typical form_for, but this user seems to be doing a custom form, and refuses to post all the code... upvoted for the references :)